# Removing last rows of each group based on condition in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframe:

```
    name    gender    count
0     A      M         3
1     A      F         2
2     A      Nan       3
3     B      NaN       2
4     C      F         4
5     D      M         5
6     D      Nan       5
```

I would like to build a resulting dataframe `df1` which deletes that last row of group of `name` attribute if the count of that group is greater than 1. For eq- `name` A is present 3 times, hence the last row containing A should be removed. B and C are only present once, hence the rows containing them should be retained.

Resulting dataframe `df1` should be like this:

```
     name    gender    count
0     A      M         3
1     A      F         2
2     B      NaN       2
3     C      F         4
4     D      M         5
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
In [4598]: (df.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:-1] if len(x)>1 else x)
              .reset_index(drop=True))
Out[4598]:
  name gender  count
0    A      M      3
1    A      F      2
2    B    NaN      2
3    C      F      4
4    D      M      5
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `groupby` + `head`:

```
g = df.groupby('name', as_index=False, group_keys=False)\
          .apply(lambda x: x.head(-1) if x.shape[0] > 1 else x)
print(g)
  name gender  count
0    A      M      3
1    A      F      2
3    B    NaN      2
4    C      F      4
5    D      M      5
```